# How to print only specific detail from String array?

Tags: java, arrays, string, printing, display

```
class temp
{
    public static void main(String []args)
    {
        String [] arp = new String [] {"Sarah is a good girl","Sarah is a bad girl"} ;// I only want to print "good" from this array and not the entire string in the below println statement.

        System.out.println(arp[0]);//this will print the entire string on element[0] while i only want to print "good" from that string.
    }
}
```

If this problem is solved then my previous question will be solved as well.

Comment: Look into `substring`

Comment: `System.out.println("good")`? Seems you need to be more specific in your question. Do you maybe want to identify the X in "Sarah is a X girl" or even "Y is a X {girl/boy}"?

Comment: @Samon Fischer Thanks for your answer but this string is just an example, there could be anything in that place not just good. I want some sort of technique or method where i could just print the fourth part where "good" is located.
"This is a fine House"
I want to print only "House" that is the fifth word or "fine" that is fourth word.

Is this possible what i am asking?

Comment: @Idos Thanks this seems like something of my interest

Answer (score 0):

Just use an if statement and String.contains

```
String[] strs = ...;
for (int i = 0; i < strs.length; i++) {
  if (strs[i].contains("good")) System.out.println("good");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use String split() function.

Example :

```
String [] arp = new String [] {"Sarah is a good girl","Sarah is a bad girl"} ;

  for (int i = 0; i < arp.length; i++) {
  String data = arp[i];
  String[] ex = data.split(" "); // You trim to remove leading and trailing spaces here
  System.out.println(ex[0]); //prints Sarah
  System.out.println(ex[1]); //prints is
  System.out.println(ex[2]); //prints a
  System.out.println(ex[3]); //prints good
  System.out.println(ex[4]); //prints girl
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It will work fine.

```
class temp{
    public static void main(String []args){
        String arp[] ="Sarah is a good girl","Sarah is a bad girl" ;
        System.out.println(arp[3]);
    }
}
```

https://ideone.com/5mDnZS

Comment: Wow... Impressive. Thanks